# How to create a python module as a single callable function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

**I'd like to write the module as a function and not a class.**

Is there a way to make this work as intended?

**`greet.py`**

```py
def main(x):
    print(f'Hello {x}!')
```

Now how do I write the module so that when `greet` is executed, `main` runs.

**`main.py`**

```py
import greet

greet('Foo') # output: Hello Foo!
```

Comment: Modules aren't functions or classes. They're modules. Why do you want `greet` itself to be callable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

An object, class, or function can be callable, but a module cannot.

You can, however, name things conveniently:

```
[greet.py]
def greet(x):
     ...

[main.py]
    from greet import greet
    greet('foo')
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering. I will accept this once the 'no-acceptions time' window closes.

Comment: @Draconis Not directly (actually, if you make a subclass of `module` with a different metaclass, it would be), but it is possible to effectively simulate that behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

**Don't do this. If you're not sure whether you need this, you don't. Making a module callable is a really weird thing to do. However, it is an interesting intellectual curiosity, so...**

It is possible to do this, exploiting the fact that a module is itself an object, and that an object is callable if its class has a `__call__` method.

However, one problem is that `module` is a builtin, and you cannot modify the attributes of a builtin.

The simplest solution, therefore, is to create a class that will take the place of the module in `sys.modules`, but also has a `__call__` method.

In `greet.py`:

```
import sys

class CallableModule():

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._wrapped.main(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return object.__getattribute__(self._wrapped, attr)

sys.modules[__name__] = CallableModule(sys.modules[__name__])

def main(x):
    print(f'Hello {x}!')
```

From the shell:

```
>>> import greet
>>> greet('there')
Hello there!
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining. I didn't realize it wasn't kosher to create callable modules. I will refrain.

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't what OP wants, but this is definitely the more fun answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @Draconis Yup, if I could make the disclaimer double-bold, I would. It was interesting to explore, though!

Comment: You might actually need such a creepy solution if you are transitioning from a bad solution to a new one and you need to support both the old and new simultaneously. But, yes, it could be avoided with more effort.

Comment: This does not always work tough sadly. If you do  
from greet import *
then greet('test') will throw an error, 'greet is not defined'.